# GPath Expression: Use HTML element's value as argument

Tags: grails, gsp

I have this gpath expression

```
<g:findAll in="${paymentList}" expr="it.account == 10">
```

and this field

```
<g:hiddenField name="acct_id"/>
```

`acct_id` already has a value and I want to use that value for comparison instead of just putting a static number like `10`. How do I do it?

Comment: replace the static 10 with the expression of setting the acct_id value

Answer (score 0):

Though first question is, from where did the value for hidden field came?

If it's known or even coming from request or in model, then we can do it like below:

**Reason for using ${} in g:set tag**  is to make the value Integer.

**Reason for using ${} in g:findAll tag's expr attribute**  is to make the value available to expr(Note: it's a string expression which gets evaluated later in taglib).

Hope it helps!